# Perl and IDA Pro

Tags: perl, debugging, reverse-engineering, ida

Could someone provide a good link to documentation/material/examples for IDA Perl (a plugin to add Perl scripting and automation support to IDA Pro)? I see there is much documentation about Python and IDA Pro but for Perl it seems there is nothing. Or could someone suggest a Perl CPAN module that automate the IDA Pro debugger?

Answer (score 2):

idaperl implements the exact same functions as ida's original IDC scripting language.

there is no higher level wrapper for iterating over interesting objects,
also there is no access to the low level internal ida api, like with idapython.

willem ( i am the author of idaperl )

Answer (score 0):

The idaapi parts of IdaPython is built with SWIG, so if you wanted you could use the SWIG definitions from IdaPython.  This would not get you the idc wrappers, as those are implemented in Python.